# Tpaнспoнирование матрицы

Tags: c, матрицы

Скажите пожалуйста в чём здесь ошибка, вроде-бы транспонируется, а вроде нет

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int m = 4, n = 4;

void transp(int (*a)[n]) {
    int t, i, j;

    //Транспонирование матрицы
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        for(j=i; j<n; j++)
        {
            t = a[i][j];
            a[i][j]=a[j][i];
            a[j][i]=t;
        }

}

int main() {
    int (*a)[n];
    a = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            scanf("%i", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    puts("----------------------");

    transp(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            printf("%3i ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Входная матрица:

```
  5   2   4   4
  2  10   9  10
  2   2   2   8
 10   3   9   3
```

Результат:

```
  5   2   2  10
  2  10   9   3
  4   2   2   9
  4  10   8   3
```

Comment: Заполните матрицу числами от 1 до 16 - так вам будет легче увидеть что происходит и понять в чем дело.

Comment: Не знаю, как вам удалось получить такой результат. Код работает корректно, результат отличается от вашего: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b8aca1c83a453fa (по ссылке я добавил печать исходной матрицы). Транспонировать неквадратные матрицы у вас так не получится, но для случая `m == n` все выглядит нормально. Вы уверены, что вы ничего не выдумываете?

Comment: Имейте, кстати, в виду, что вы невольно используете VLA (Variable Length Arrays), хотя никакой необходимости в вашем коде в этом нет.

Comment: @AnT действительно правильно работает, компилятор походу у меня плохой )

Comment: Что за компилятор?

Comment: @AnT MinGw + IDE Clion

Comment: @AnT всё, разобрался )

Answer (score -1):

Прога работает с матрицей

```
int (*a)[n];
a = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));
```

а выделяете память только под **int**-ы. Можно подправить так:

```
int * a[m];    
for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
   a[i]=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

При траснонировании меняется формат матрицы с `m*n` -> `n*m` . Так-что функция будет пахать только на квадратных.
Вариант второй без использования вектора векторов.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int m = 4, n = 4;

int * addr(int * a , int i , int j){ return a+i+(j*n);}

void transp ( int * a ) {
    int t, i, j;
    //Транспонирование матрицы
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)        {
            t = * addr(a,i,j);
            * addr(a,i,j) = * addr(a,j,i);
            * addr(a,j,i) = t ;     } }

int main() {
    int * a ;
    int i,j;
    a = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            scanf("%i", addr(a,i,j));        }   }

    puts("----------------------");

    transp(a);

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)  printf("%3i ", * addr(a,i,j));
        printf("\n");    }

    free(a);
    return 0;}
```

Результат

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
----------------------
  1   5   9  13 
  2   6  10  14 
  3   7  11  15 
  4   8  12  16
```

Comment: Выделение памяти в исходном коде сделано совершенно правильно. Матрица - это и есть int-ы. В данном случае было бы лучше `a = malloc(m * sizeof *a);`, как всегда. Но и исходный вариант верен. Предложенный же вами вариант - грубо неправилен и работает с неинициализированным указателем.

Comment: Теперь, после исправления, вы предлагаете заменить исходный "монолитный" массив, на "рваный" массив с множественным выделением памяти, как-будто предполагая, что это "правильнее". Это ничем не правильнее и ваш "рваный" массив тут совершенно неуместен. Особенно если учесть, что мы решаем задачу *транспонирования*. Исходный метод выделения памяти идеально для этого подходит, т.к. в случае `m != n` память не придется перевыделять. А у вас матрицу придется пересоздавать заново.

Comment: Я хотел показать как быстрее подправить код.

Comment: Подправить? Зачем? Вы нашли какую-то ошибку?

Comment: Я уж испугался, действительно пашет. Язык C подзабыл наверное.